# Cannot Edit Wordpress Website with Elementor ("Updating Failed")

Tags: wordpress

Without changing anything in particular, my Wordpress website started acting up. Every time I try to make a modification (such as setting the page from Private to Public) I get a red message telling me "Updating Failed". I also cannot access the page builder (Elementor) and I cannot view a preview of the page (it loads forever). Even when I try to customize appearance it shows me a  blank page instead of my website. The only way for me to see pages is if I set it to "Public". I only get an "Oops! That page can’t be found." if it's set to Private. So even as an admin, I don't see that small black bar on top of a private page, I simply see a default page as if I am a visitor trying to access the website.

I have tried disabling all plugins, I have tried to revert to previous versions of Wordpress (which I reinstalled) and previous version of plugins. I have also tried to modify the permalink structure (going from one setting to another and back again so it resets). I have also tried to disable the theme/change to another one. Finally, I also tried to use the classic page builder plugin. Nothing seems to work.

I think it's also worth mentioning that the problem started when I first tried to log in to the admin dashboard. If I attempt to log in via /wp-admin it doesn't work, I simply get the same screen over and over (login doesn't fail, it just doesn't do anything). However, when I switch to /wp-login and input the same details that's when I am able to log in without any issues.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I also read that this might be an issue with permissions but I'm not entirely sure what to do about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution! I had to modify the wp-config.php file. I inserted a couple of lines into the file with VS Code (just replace "example" with your website:

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

You can find more details here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/